# Apache Apollo Examples JAVA

Tags: java, apache, activemq-classic, apollo

Can any one provide example on Apache Apollo Queue producer and consumer from JAVA ? 
Earlier I was using Apache ActiveMQ but now I want to migrate.

Comment: What have you tried?  What client do you want to use?  Expand the question to be a real question.

Answer (score 5):

There are several examples in the Apollo distribution.  The ones you want to look at are located in the following distribution directories:

- examples/openwire/java
- examples/stomp/java
- examples/mqtt/java
- examples/amqp/java

Comment: Thanks for sharing example locations. I will share my code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the protocol supported by Apollo then I dont see any changes required in the producer and consumer if they are already sending messages to ActiveMQ. Except the broker url if that has changed.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to get the following jar files:
https://people.apache.org/~rgodfrey/qpid-java-amqp-1-0-client-jms.html and the javax.jms one. After that it's pretty simple to use the examples that come with apollo.

I start a listener from the bin folder using:
java -cp example/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.jar:example/javax.jms-3.1.2.2.jar:example/qpid-amqp-1-0-client-0.22.jar:example/qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms-0.22.jar:example/qpid-amqp-1-0-common-0.22.jar:. example.Listener topic://event

and similar for the Producer.